# oauth flickr api using httr to retrieve token

Tags: r, oauth, flickr, httr

I would like to use `httr` to link up/upload my R image outputs to flickr, but am having difficulty with the initial stages where i need to authenticate myself using OAuth 1.0.

I previously created an app by going to the following link http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/

and then got a secret and key string for that app...

I then used it in the `httr` package function to get a token but to no avail. I have been trying to use the provided documentation on this link  http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html  to help out but, I am struggling...

The following is the code I used.

```
flickr.app <- oauth_app("flickr",key="xxxxxx", secret="xxxxxxxx")
flickr.urls <- oauth_endpoint(request="http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token",
                              authorize="http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize",
                              access="http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token")
flickr.token <- oauth1.0_token(flickr.urls,flickr.app)
```

from which i get the error message

```
Error: http client error (400)
```

Not too sure where to go from here...any help would be much appreciated.

N.B. Also I recognise that due to the nature of setting up api links, that there are secrets , api-keys, logins and passwords that need to be kept secret etc, but it does not take long to set up a dummy flickr account from www.flickr.com , to be able to reproduce the problem...in my opinion...perhaps others could try setting one up and letting me know if they got similar issues, and potential methods to work around the situation?

Comment: What version of `httr` are you using?

Comment: The easiest way for me to help with these problems is for you to email me a minimal reproducible example on a dummy flickr account (or if you trust me a lot, with your regular flick account)

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the httr library, but I recently (as of yesterday) just finished writing from scratch Objective-C code to access Flickr. The biggest pain point for me was figuring out how to correctly encode the signature. I don't know the httr library well enough, but if I had to guess my guess would be that it is not encoding the signature properly.

If you read through this: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

You will find very detailed instructions on how to authorize with Flickr - it was useful to me because I wrote the code in Objective C from scratch. Might be less useful to you unless you are able to debug through the httr source and figure out if it is doing things exactly as Flickr expects.